# Editor.js/embed Rumble integration

Tags: embed, editorjs

Looking at the documentation of **editor.js/embed** [plugin](https://github.com/editor-js/embed#add-more-services), the `id()` function is not `async`, it seems therefore impossible to fetch metadata information about a rumble link from server
For example, a link like this doesn't contain any information about the video id:
https://rumble.com/v1h7lsx-jordan-peterson-skewers-trudeau.html (v1h7lsx is not the id surprisingly enough)

Looking to synchronous javascript fetch through XMLHttpRequest, the feature seams to be discontinued (or threatening discontinuation soon on the main browsers).

What would be your advice to embed rumble videos?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate Rumble tool that will specify [pasteConfig](https://editorjs.io/tools-api#pasteconfig) for handling such links. The tool could have backend meta fetch logic.

```
class RumbleTool {
  static get pasteConfig() {
    return {
      patterns: {
        image: /https?:\/\/rumble.com\/\S+/i
      }
    }
  }
  onPaste(event){
    switch (event.type){
      case 'pattern':
        const url = event.detail.data;

        this.fetchMetaByUrl(url);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

See the example and detailed explanation: https://editorjs.io/paste-substitutions#create-blocks-from-pasted-link